# Microsoft Graph 'created' subscription is not working with application token

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a working application integrated with Microsoft Graph with application token received with a certificate.
I can subscribe to "updated,deleted" events on user contacts and calendars but I can't subscribe to "updated,deleted,created".

Resource used `/users/<email>/contacts` and `/users/<email>/calendars`

It gives me the following error on POST `/subscriptions` :

```
error": {
"code": "ExtensionError",
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "<skip>",
  "date": "<skip>"
}
```

I just checked with a sandbox and it works with a user authenticated (I haven't check fully but at least it timeouts on a server side). Though with application token it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: 'User and group notifications support updated and deleted changeType.'

Reference:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription

Comment: This is absolutely not clear. "User and group notifications" means /users and /groups to me. And I'm referring to /contacts and /calendars. More over it works in Graph Explorer in case I have user authenticated. So the issue is more with Application token

Comment: For example this link https://www.eliostruyf.com/creating-and-renewing-your-microsoft-graph-webhook-subscriptions/ confirms that at least it was working with Application token.

Answer (score 0):

Drive root item notifications support only the updated changeType. User and group notifications support updated and deleted changeType.

Comment: What drive, user and group has to do with calendars and contacts? It works it Graph Explorer by the way. It doesn't work with Application token.

Comment: Application token is typically registered with dev.apps.microsoft.com, and may differ from Azure Application. Could you share where do you get your token?

Comment: Sorry, Bruce. I misguided. I tried to use wrong link for calendars and thought that contacts were not working. Now everyhting is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made something wrong in the beginning. 
`/users/<email>/calendars` is a wrong link. To get user events it should be `/users/<email>/calendar/events`.

And `/users/<email>/contacts` created is working properly.